# Dynamic proxy classes in C++. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, dynamic-proxy

First of all, let me say that I'm not a guru C++ programmer. I have a few years of experience in C++, but my main area is .NET/C#.

I'm looking into a way to create dynamic proxy/wrapper classes in C++. Particularly, what I want to achieve is to intercept a method call. This kind of tricks is common in Java/.NET world, but C++ lacks Reflection.

I found an [online tutorial](http://cppguru.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/c-proxy-template/), which explains how to create a wrapper and intercept method calls through -> operator overloading:

```
class Person{
  std::string mName;
  Person(std::string pName): mName(name){}
  void printName(){
     std::cout << mName << std::endl;
  }

};

template <class T >
class Wrap {
     T * p ;
     public:
             Wrap (T * pp ) :p (pp) { }
             Call_proxy <T> operator ->() {
                   prefix ();
                   return Call_proxy<T>(p);
             }
};
template <class T >
class Call_proxy {
       T * p ;
       public :
              Call_proxy (T * pp ) :p (pp ){ }
              ˜Call_proxy () {
                     suffix ();
               }
               T * operator ->() {
                          return p ;
                }
 };
```

As you can see from this sample, we can catch method calls events, before and after call, but what is not clear for me, is how to detect which method is being called? Is it possible at all?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Allright, to make things more clear, I don't really care if the implementation would be truly dynamic or not. Having a wrapper class similar to smart pointers is fine for me.

Comment: Can you give some kind of code example of what you would want to do? Clearly this code has no idea what methods the class has. So even if some other piece of code knew the method, what could it give this code?

Comment: The simple answer here is 'no'. C++ has only the simplest kinds of introspection. You could conceivably implement your own function table and handle the dispatching yourself and provide this sort of functionality, but there would be big overheads. Alternatively, if you only wanted to deal with a small number of classes you could create subclasses rather than proxies. If you were dealing with spefifically named functions you could implement them explicitly in your proxy. Aside from that, I think you're out of luck!

Comment: Probably it's only me, but what "reflection" has to do with "Dynamic proxy classes" ? reflection is about data structures and their ability to describe themself. As first answer I would say that you are looking for a policy class mechanism as the one described by Andrei Alexandrescu in his own book on modern C++.

Comment: the code that you posted adds simply a method before and after the method that you are calling (using raii powertool). Is it want you want? What do you mean with:" I want to achieve is to intercept a method call"?

Comment: can you show as some c# code that do the job? It may be helpful to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is your platform Windows or Linux ?

Comment: Incidentally, reflection does *not* allow what you intend to do, and neither Java nor C# routinely employ this technique. It *is* possible in both – but not through reflection, and it’s complex enough to be reserved for rather specific libraries (it requires rewriting intermediate code).

Comment: @KonradRudolph how this differs from the policy class idea of Andrei Alexandrescu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is designed specifically to be non intrusive, All the wrappers do is facilitate the calling of prefix and suffix and then return the object that is being referenced so that it can call the specified function.   If the -> operator is overloaded then, object->function() gets expanded to object.operator->()->function().

Here is a link to the paper Stroustrup wrote, it's very informative http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf